# Cache of site on browser

Tags: media, cache

I am making a wordpress site and it contains a media link. As when media file on server changes it don't get updated on my site. To see my new media i have to open new tab in browser, otherwise it is displaying previous results as media is cached in browser.
Even if i refresh the page it is displaying previous result. to see updated result i had only to open my site in new tab.
How could i solve this problem.

Comment: don't use the same url for different media?

Comment: downvoting and close voting since in its current state the question is very generic and is not specific to wordpress

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to clean the cache (using Chrome and Windows) you can:

1. Open Developer Tools - F12
2. Right click on the reload button
3. Choose
   an option from the dropdown menu - probably the last - "Empty cache
   and hard reload"

Comment: First hard reloading is not updating my media.  Secondly I want to change something in my site not in my own browser

Comment: I don't know why opening page in another tab should update you source, unless you have something coded this way, but the you should show us the code or give more info on that otherwise it looks like you have a problem with a browser's cache.

Answer (score 0):

I would try running the WordPress plugin called "busted!" which "refreshes the browser cache for a file if it has been modified"
https://wordpress.org/plugins/busted

It is two years old, so YMMV.

Answer (score -1):

You can clear your browser cache by hard reloading your browser.

For Windows,

Press CTRL + SHIFT + R

For Mac,

Press CMD + SHIFT + R

Comment: First hard reloading is not updating my media.

Comment: Secondly I want to change something in my site not in my own browser.

Comment: @Mukul could you please share jsfiddle or website link so that I can help you out...